# Exactly two duplicated in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code to populate data on the uitableview cell. For some reason, I see every item exactly two on the tableview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"takeStockCell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RackStockTakeStatus *rackStockTakeStatus = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = rackStockTakeStatus.locName;
    if ([[rackStockTakeStatus.status lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"inprogress"])
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%@]",rackStockTakeStatus.status,rackStockTakeStatus.stockTakeByUser];
    } else if ([[rackStockTakeStatus.status lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"completed"])
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(102/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%@]",rackStockTakeStatus.status,rackStockTakeStatus.stockTakeByUser];
    } else if ([[rackStockTakeStatus.status lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"verified"])
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(102/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%@]",rackStockTakeStatus.status,rackStockTakeStatus.stockTakeByUser];
    }
}
```

Comment: You could print your datasource array and will see how there your objects are

Comment: Data source data is perfect, no duplicates there

Comment: put a breakpoint and see it gets hit more than the required times

Comment: @saif does the number of rows visible in tableview is also get doubled?

Comment: Print tabbel cell row numbers to see if rown not doubled and check if you not getting datasource twice

Comment: @Akhilrajtr yes number of rows is getting incremented. I am using data from NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: @Anton, seems like something wrong in the delegate. I am printing indexPath.row in configureCell function (shown in my quesion), it is printing in weird way:

Index Path 0
Index Path 1
Index Path 2
Index Path 3
Index Path 4
Index Path 5
Index Path 6
Index Path 7
Index Path 8
Index Path 9
Index Path 10
Index Path 11
Index Path 12
Index Path 13
Index Path 14
Index Path 15
Index Path 0
Index Path 2
Index Path 4
Index Path 6
Index Path 8

First it prints 1,2....... n then 0, 2, 4, 6 not sure why

Comment: So thios is a problem. review your cellforrowatindexpath method. There is some bug. it's datasource. You are not building your cell in right way

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your method configuring the cell like that. Have you tried to configure it directly into the method cellForRowAtIndexPath ? Not putting the cell as a parameter.

Or just returning the cell in your method configure

```
cell = [self configureCell...
```